# Server separate connection per client

Tags: connection, client-server

The simple way to support multiple clients is to fork a process for each incoming connection and handle the client through that process and the other process then listens on the default port.
However I have heard that not only is the process forked, but the connection itself is redirected from the default port at which the server is listening to a different port on the server side. This improves performance. I am unable to find any reliable reference to this topic. Is this a standard procedure

Answer (score 0):

This is not the case for most protocols on the internet. For example, public web servers will always listen on port 80 for every request. FTP servers on port 21 and so on. Where did you get your information? With more information on the context, someone might be able to help establish the circumstances you're talking about. What's your source?

Comment: It was from some chit-chat with a 'socket programming expert'. I have 'googled' for answers, but no results so far.

Comment: @Patricia - Not yet.